# How to modify a string that contains a character within a condition using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following string x = "BTGGg.F"

Using python, and the if condition that if there is a lowercase letter before the ".", I want to drop it I would use the following function.

```
x = "BTGGg.F"
if x[x.find(".")-1].islower:
    x = x.replace(x[x.find(".")-1],"")
```

I would get "BTGG.F"

Is there a way to do this same thing using a regex function or some one line function?

Comment: I would ignore that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

x = "BTGGg.F"

print( re.sub(r'([a-z])(?=\.)', '', x) )
```

Prints:

```
BTGG.F
```

Comment: thanks this is perfect, could you take a look at this question for me ? I can't seem to solve it maybe u might have an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921897/how-to-modify-a-column-of-strings-in-pandas-using-a-few-conditionals-regex

Comment: @anarchy I posted an answer to that question as well.